# postgres 9.3 database trigger creation

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am trying to create a trigger that on update of one table, runs a query and updates another table with the results.

Where I am getting stuck, is assigning the result of the query to a correctly typed variable.

The current error is that the array must start with "{" or other dimensional information however as I make tweaks I get other errors

Please see my current code below and let me know the best approach

Your help is very appreciated as I have spent a huge amount of time consulting google.

```
CREATE TYPE compfoo AS (ownership character varying (50), count INT);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test1_update() RETURNS trigger AS
$$

DECLARE
largest_owner   character varying (50);
temp_result compfoo[];

BEGIN

SELECT ownership, count(*) INTO temp_result
  FROM austpoly2 
  WHERE ownership IS NOT NULL
  group by ownership 
  ORDER BY count DESC
  LIMIT 1;


largest_owner = temp_result[0].ownership;

UPDATE public.states
   SET ownership= largest_owner
 WHERE statecode='1';

RETURN NEW;

  END;

$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER test1_update_trigger
BEFORE UPDATE ON austpoly2
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE test1_update();
```

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thankyou a_horse with_no_name

Your response combined with

```
temp_result    compfoo%ROWTYPE;
```

solved this problem